# Why does .2.2.2 in Spotlight equal 0.0016?

Tags: macos, spotlight

If you use Spotlight in macOS with the `.` operator such as ‘.1.1.1.1’ the result is ‘0.0001’. What operations are being processed by Spotlight? `.2.2.2 = 0.0016`

[image: .2.2.2.2.2.2 = 0.000064]

Answer (score 1):

It's *supposed* to be multiplication, which in scientific notation is signified by placing the operands adjacent to one another (operators such as "*" or "x" are optional). I say *supposed* to be multiplication because .2 times .2 times .2 equals .008, not .0016 as presented in your question. I suspect you didn't gather the entire string for your title, and another .2 was present.

Your screen shot, on the other hand, correctly gives 0.000064 as the result of .2 * .2 * .2 * .2 * .2 * .2. Since that operation is the same as asking for .2 to the sixth power, entering ".2^6" into spotlight will return the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with .2 it shows that .2 = 0.2. This tells you that it's ready .2 as 0.2.

If you do .2.2 it shows .2.2 = 0.04. What operation performed on 0.2 and 0.2 would result in 0.04?

Hopefully you've now answered your own question. If not…

> 0.2 * 0.2 = 0.04